# Catch Javascript onclick events in an HTML page hosted in a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Given an HTML document like this, hosted inside a WebView, how do I catch click events so they can be handled by my code, rather than the WebView?

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.blah.com/blah';">
```

The HTML is provided from another source, so it is desirable to to handle click events on the HTML without altering the HTML document as I cannot make assumptions about its structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `addJavaScriptInterfaceMethod()` in WebView.

Also more information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) in the **Binding JavaScript code to Android code** section.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a JavaScript interface (`addJavascriptInterface`) to your Webview and you can then call Java objects from your javascript code.

Check this:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))

You then create a function that is called on click, calling your registered Java object.